# $G$-bundles on affine spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, principal-bundles

Let $G$ be a connected algebraic group. Is it true that every $G$-bundle on 
${\mathbb A}^n$ is trivial? What is the reference?
I am actually only interested in the case $n=2$.

Comment: From the context, I assume `$G$` is to be an affine algebraic group.   The reductive case has been most studied, so it's also important to indicate if more generality is wanted.

Comment: Yes, I meant that $G$ is affine and $G$ reductive is sufficient for me (in fact, at least in characteristic $0$ it is clear that everything
reduces to the reductive case).

Answer (score 7):

This is true for $G=GL(r)$, as shown by Quillen and Suslin.

For arbitrary $G$ there are counterexamples. Quite surprisingly, even $G$-bundles over $\textrm{Spec }k$ may not be trivial. See the paper

M. S. Raghunathan

"[Principal bundles on affine space and bundles on the projective line](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01443521)",

Mathematische Annalen
Volume 285, Number 2, 309–332

Comment: This 1989 paper can be accessed freely at the German archive gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/   It would help to unpack Raghunathan's theorems (and his previous results) a little more, since he is mainly concerned with reductive groups over arbitrary fields.  If I understand correctly, groups over algebraically closed fields are better behaved in the current context.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look at the paper. I am actually interested in the (split) reductive case but possibly over finite field. I wonder if there is a counterexample in that case.

Answer (score 6):

Over an algebraically closed field, for $G$ connected and reductive, every principal $G$-bundle on ${\Bbb A}^n$ is trivial, also by a theorem of Raghunathan:

"Principal bundles on affine space", in *C. P. Ramanujam—a tribute*, pp. 187–206, Tata Inst. Fund. Res. Studies in Math. **8** (1978).

(Unfortunately I can't find this reference free online.)

Comment: This is reference [15] in Raghunathan's later paper mentioned by Francesco Polizzi.   Is there a more accessible later reference for the algebraically closed case?   

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if the same is true over finite field?

Comment: @Jim: Good question, I haven't been able to find a simpler reference.

@Alexander: I'm no expert in this, but the strongest general results so far seem to be in an IHES paper from 1992 by Colliot-Thelene and Ojanguren.  However, "infinite" is one of their hypotheses on the ground field -- but I don't think they give counter examples.

Comment: @Alexander: I'm unaware of any explicit formulation for a reductive group defined over a finite field; but I'm not familiar enough with this literature.

Comment: The 1992 IHES paper [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46127/g-bundles-on-affine-spaces#comment111586_46134) by @DaveAnderson:  [Colliot-Thélène and  Ojanguren - Espaces principaux homogènes localement triviaux](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1992__75__97_0).

Answer (score 4):

In characteristic $p$ you can make an easy counterexample with $n=1$, right? An exact sequence of commutative algebraic groups $0\to E\to X\to \mathbb A\to 0$ with $E$ an elliptic curve.

Comment: Interesting -- but how does ${\Bbb A} = {\Bbb G}_a$ act on $E$?

Comment: This is a naive question, but does this give us something for n=2, namely $E\times A \to X\times A \to A^2$?

Comment: I meant: Choose an elliptic curve $E$ (over a given field $k$ of characteristic $p$) that has a subgroup of order $p$ (i.e. has a $k$-rational point of order $p$). In $\mathhbb G_a$ there is also a subgroup of order $p$, with quotient isomorphic to $\mathbb G_a$. In $E\times \mathbb G_a$ there is a 'diagonal' subgroup of order $p$. Divide out by it to get $X$. 

Comment: You can also take a supersingular elliptic curve as both it and $\mathbb G_a$ contains an $\alpha_p$.

Comment: Well, my question was imprecise - I meant "linear algebraic group".

Comment: And my answer was cheating: my "bundle" was not locally trivial in the Zariski topology.

Comment: At least for connected reductive groups $G$, don't you only ask $G$-bundles to be locally trivial in the etale topology?  For $G = GL_n$ this gives nothing new, but my impression was that for a more general $G$ there aren't so many $G$-bundles locally trivial in the Zariski topology.

Comment: I don't know. I'm just a topologist playing along.

Comment: In the Chevalley seminar, the question of whether (etale-locally trivial) principal $G$-bundles are always Zariski-locally trivial arose, and was settled: they're called "special groups" and are essentially products of $GL_n$, $SL_n$, and $Sp_{2n}$.  However, the question remains if you make restrictions on the base, as we're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

By Thm. 1.1 of [Česnavičius - The Bass–Quillen phenomenon for reductive group torsors](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Ekestutis.cesnavicius/BQ-equicharacteristic.pdf), for a field $k$ and a $k$-totally isotropic reductive group $G$, every generically trivial $G$-torsor on $\mathbb{A}^{n}_k$ is trivial.

Comment: For someone who's only used to working over fields, what does "$k$-totally isotropic" mean of a reductive group?  Is it the same as being split?

Comment: Not it means that for if you decompose the adjoint group G_{ad} as a product of simple adjoint groups, each of them contains a non-split torus. In particular a quasi-split is totally isotropic. See def. 8.1 here: https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~kestutis.cesnavicius/split-unramified.pdf